# Can bind be useful here? Duplication of code

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

I am new to javascript and thats my pen: [pen](http://codepen.io/irainbow/pen/apxxaE)

so i have faced such problem as duplication of code. how can I avoid it? I have tried this new fuction instead of old ones but its not working:

```
//populatePosition($("#positionElement"));
populate1($("#positionElement"), positionList, 'position');

function populate1(dd, list, elem) {
  var temp="";
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
     temp += "<option value='" + list[i]["id"] + "'>" + list[i][''+elem] + "</option>\n";
     //console.log(temp);
  }
  dd.append(temp);
}
```

I guess bind can be used here. is it possible?

Comment: where would you use bind in that code and for what purpose

Comment: maybe bind is unnecessary here. how can i get rid of duplication?

Comment: I see no duplication in the code you posted!

Comment: at codepen, there are 2 similar function populating lists.

Comment: oh, that's why there's nothing in the question